# Why Query Exception Updating Data in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to updating data in laravel.view and delete part works fine but updating part is not working. it is giving query exception

> QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'add_teachers.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `add_teachers`
>   where `add_teachers`.`id` = 2 limit 1)

my **web.php** file is

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::get('login',  function(){
    return view('login');
});

Route::post('login','logincontro@checklogin');
Route::get('logout','logincontro@logout');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'checklogin'], function () {

Route::get('dashboard','dashboard@home');

Route::get('add-student', function() {

       return view('add-student');
});

Route::get('add-teacher', function() {

       return view('add-teacher');
});

Route::get('view-student', function() {

       return view('view-student');
});

Route::get('view-teacher', function() {

       return view('view-teacher');
});



Route::get('view-student', 'addStudents@addstudentHome');

Route::post('/insert', 'addStudents@addstudentData');

Route::get('/update/{id}', 'addStudents@updatestudentData');

Route::post('/edit/{id}', 'addStudents@editstudentData');

Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'addStudents@deletestudentData');



Route::get('view-teacher', 'addTeachers@addteacherHome');

Route::post('/insert', 'addTeachers@addteacherData');

Route::get('/update1/{teacher_id}', 'addTeachers@updateteacherData');

Route::post('/edit/{id}', 'addTeachers@editteacherData');

Route::get('/delete/{id}', 'addTeachers@deleteteacherData');

    });
```

**view-teacher.blade.php** code is

```
 @if(count($addData)> 0)

  @foreach($addData -> all() as $singleData)
                <tr>

                <td>{{ $singleData -> teacher_id }}</td>

            <td> <img style="width:65px;" src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $singleData -> teacher_image }}" alt="image" /> </td>
            <td>{{ $singleData -> teacher_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleData -> position }}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleData -> contact_num }}</td>
            <td>{{ $singleData -> teacher_email }}</td>
            <td> 
                <a href='{{ url("/update1/{$singleData -> teacher_id}")}}' class="label label-success" style="font-size:14px "> Update</a> 
                <a href='{{ url("/delete/{$singleData -> teacher_id}")}}' class="label label-danger" onClick="return doconfirm();" style="font-size:14px "> Delete</a>   
             </td>

             </tr>


        @endforeach
        @endif
```

Controller addTeachers.php is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\addTeacher;

class addTeachers extends Controller
{

    public function addteacherHome()
    {
            $addData = addTeacher::all();

      return view('view-teacher', ['addData' => $addData]);

    }


    public function addteacherData(Request $request)

    {
            $this -> validate($request, 
             [ 
               'teacher_name' => 'required',
               'position'  => 'required',
               'contact_num' => 'required',
               'teacher_email'  => 'required',
               'teacher_image'  => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5048'   ]);


         $image = $request -> file('teacher_image'); 

         $destinationPath = 'images/';

         $filename = $image -> getClientOriginalName(); 

         $image -> move($destinationPath, $filename);


         /*Storage::put('upload/image/'.$filename, file_get_contents($request -> file('image')-> getRealPath()));*/

         $datas = new addTeacher;

         $datas -> teacher_name = $request -> input('teacher_name');

         $datas -> position  = $request -> input('position');

         $datas -> contact_num = $request -> input('contact_num');

         $datas -> teacher_email = $request -> input('teacher_email');

         $datas -> teacher_image = $filename;

         $datas -> save();

         return redirect('/add-teacher')-> with('info', 'Data saved Successfully');




    }


    public function updateteacherData(Request $request, $teacher_id)

    {

        $updateData = addTeacher::find($teacher_id);

      return view('update-teacher', ['updateData' => $updateData] );


    }


    public function editteacherData(Request $request, $id)  {



$this -> validate($request, 
           [ 
               'teacher_name' => 'required',
               'position'  => 'required',
               'contact_num' => 'required',
               'teacher_email'  => 'required',
               'teacher_image'  => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5048'   ]);


         $image = $request -> file('teacher_image'); 

         $destinationPath = 'images/';

         $filename = $image -> getClientOriginalName(); 

         $image -> move($destinationPath, $filename);

       $data = array(

         'teacher_name' => $request -> input('teacher_name'),

         'position' => $request -> input('position'),

         'contact_num' => $request -> input('contact_num'),

         'teacher_email' => $request -> input('teacher_email'),

         'teacher_image' => $filename
    );

    addTeacher::where('teacher_id', $id) -> update($data);

     return redirect('view-teacher') -> with('info', 'Data Updated successfully');

    }


    public function deleteteacherData($id)

    {

         addTeacher::where('teacher_id', $id) -> delete();

    return redirect('view-teacher') -> with('info', 'Data Deleted successfully');


    }
}
```

Table structure>>>
[image]

Comment: Can you provide teacher table structure

Comment: you are having primary key as `teacher_id` right?

Comment: yes, teacher_id is primary key

Comment: table structure given

Comment: have u updated model?

Comment: which part have to update?

Comment: open model and write the lines given in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, Laravel takes `id` as the primary key when you are using `find` it looks the given id into the `id` field of the table so what you need to do is just open teacher model and write following line

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'teacher_id';

    // all the other methods
}
```

Or you can use where instead of using find method just like below

```
$data = Teacher::where('teacher_id',$teacher_id)->get();
```

This will also work same as find method without updating the model.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel assumes id to be primary key.
So you have used teacher_id as primary key.

Laravel `Model::find()` uses `id` as default primary key.

You can override the primary key to be your custom key like this.

In your `addTeacher` Model add this line.

`protected $primaryKey='teacher_id';`

Or else you can also do like this in your `updateteacherData()` method

replace 
`$updateData = addTeacher::find($teacher_id);`

with

`$updateData = addTeacher::where('teacher_id',$teacher_id)->get()->first();`